# div no aparece con cakePHP 3.6

Tags: cakephp, div

Hola tengo un layout y dentro de este cargo contenido a través de fetch('content') ?>

Las vistas en cakePHP 3.6 se guardan en src/template --> Vista/vista.ctp

Pues tengo una vista que es un código muy sencillo, hace un foreach y muestro dentro de un div el resultado.

Pues bien, funciona todo pero el div lo obvia, me estoy volviendo loco, porque no se porque no lo muestra, pongo el código de la vista:

```
<?php foreach($textos as $texto): ?>
  <?= $texto->texto; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php $historia = $texto[0]['texto']; ?>

<div id='historia'>
    <?= $historia; ?>
</div>
```

y claro, el id de div esta asociado a unos estilos y al no aparecer pues no se cargan. Pobre a meter dentro del código de PHP, mostrando con echo, pero tampoco funciono.

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontré el problema:

```
<div id="historia">
  <?php foreach($textos as $texto): ?>
    <?= $texto->texto; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Parece ser que si mostraba el div, pero me lo mostraba al final y vació, pero de esta forma lo muestra sin problema.

Saludos